# Searching for a value and getting the row values in ASPxGridView

Tags: gridview, aspxgridview

I have an `ASPxGridView` with two columns: `siteName` and `siteIP`. `KeyFieldName` is `siteName`.

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="gridSiteList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" KeyFieldName="siteName">
         <Columns>
               <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="siteName" VisibleIndex="1" Caption="Name">
               </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
               <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="siteIP" VisibleIndex="2" Caption="IP" Visible="False">
               </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
         </Columns>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

I want to look for an IP address in the gridview and get the matching siteName.

`GetRowValuesByKeyValue()` method looks for `siteName` and brings `siteIP`. I want to do the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ASPxGridView.GetRowValues](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_GetRowValuestopic) and search for row with value you need. 
However, I think you should query database directly instead.